# Equivalence between function spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I´m reading Barmaks´s *Algebraic topology of finite topological space and applications*, and in some moment the author says that:

$$Hom(X\times Z, Y)=Hom(Z,Hom(X,Y))$$
(Where $X,Y,Z$ are topological spaces, and $Hom(X,Y)$ is equipped with the compact-open topology)

It´s obvious that the continuity of $f:X\times Z\rightarrow Y$ implies the continuity of $\phi(f):Z\rightarrow Hom(X,Y)$, but the author claims that if each point of $X$ has a basis of compact neighborhoods, i.e that for every open set $U$ containing $x$ there exists a compact neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U$, then the converse is true. How could I prove that?

Thank you for your time.

(EDIT)

SOLUTION:

Let´s we prove first that (under the assumptions done before) the application 
$$e:X\times Hom(X,Y)\rightarrow Y,\hspace{0.3cm}e(x,f)=f(x)$$
is continuous.

Let us consider $(x,f)\in X\times Hom(X,Y)$ and $V$ an open set containing $f(x)$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists an open set $U'_{x}$ containing $x$ such $f(U_{x})\subset V$, using the hypothesis of the statement, there exists a compact neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U$. Then, we can consider a open set $U_{x}\subset C$ containing $x$. It´s clear now that the set $U_{x}\times S(C,V)$ (where $S(C,V)=\{f\in Hom(X,Y) : f(C)\subset V\}$ it´s an element of the sub-base for the compact-open topology) it´s open in $X\times Hom(X,Y)$ and $e(U_{x},S(C,V))\subset V$ by construction. Then, $e$ is continuous.

Finally the application $\phi(f)$ can be obtained as the following composition of continuous applications:
$$i_{x}\times \phi(f):X\times Z\rightarrow X\times Hom(X,Y)$$
$$e:X\times Hom(X,Y)\rightarrow Y$$

Hence, $f$ is continuous.